# Select Statement in SSMS does not show results

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I came across a weird behavior in SSMS 18 wherein my select statement does not show any grid as a result even thought my results to grid is enabled. What might I be missing?

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

All options are unticked in query results -> results to grid.

[image]

`SETPARSEONLY` and `SETNOEXEC` are unticked in query execution -> advanced.

[image]

Comment: Everything in the settings is unticked by default @Charlieface

Comment: What about the Query Execution -> Advanced tab, is `SET PARSEONLY`  or `SET NOEXEC` selected

Comment: same, they are unticked @Charlieface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your screenshot shows that you have an active text-selection covering `UPDATE` statement; the Execute button in SSMS will only run the entire file/script/batch when no text is currently selected, [otherwise it only executes the currently selected text as its own batch/script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/f1-help/database-engine-query-editor-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-ver16#:%7E:text=Executes%20the%20selected%20code%20or%2C%20if%20no%20code%20is%20selected%2C%20it%20executes%20all%20the%20Query%20Editor%20code.).

...so in your case, you've been running only the `UPDATE` statement without the preceding `SELECT` hence why you get the "(3 rows affected)" mmessage but no query results grid.

So de-select all text first, *then* press F5.

Comment: ah, I didn't know ssms would only run highlighted queries. Thank you for that info!!